# Postgres: Is there a way to target specific tables based on your data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I'm currently thinking about an effective way to build out my database. It's a language learning application and I'm torn between two approaches:

1. Keeping all of my words, regardless of their language, in one giant `words` table
2. Splitting my words into separate tables based on their language, ie: `words_french`, `words_italian`, etc.

In the second scenario, are there approaches that I can use (perhaps within Postgres) that would allow me target the `words_french` table in the event that I'm currently working through french lessons / content and need to lookup associated french words?

I feel like there would be some sort of concat process like so: `words_${language}` and as of this moment I'd figure i'd have to resolve this within JS or something else on the frontend.

-- also, is breaking words and other content into their respective `table_language` even a valid approach?

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the first approach.

Comment: Why not go with two tables: `words` and `languages`. You can have a `language_id` column in the `words` table, which will represent the relationship between `words` and `languages`. Anyway, questions like this are hard to answer on stackoverflow, because every person may have a different opinion on the "best" approach.

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski  You and OP propose mixing data with metadata.  That is a terrible idea.

Comment: I found this post because I was looking at `sql`, but this really has nothing to do with `sql` or `postgresql`.  This is a `data-modeling` question.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I'm curious what you mean by that, if you have a moment could you explain it?

Comment: @MikeOrganek I know that this is offtopic for this question, but can you explain why?

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski  I misread your comment.  Your approach is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Option 1.  Option 2 would be horribly difficult to work with.

Word table:

| WordId | Word | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | English |
| 2 | un | French |

As Dimitar Spasovski suggests, if you have a need for additional attributes associated with the language, you should also have a `Language` table.  Then replace the `Language` column in the `Word` with `LanguageId` to make the relationship.

Watching or reading some data modeling or data architecture classes online will help.

Comment: Thank you, the same thought occurred to me in regards to` Language`, I think making a new table would be the best choice for it. + I'll look for some data modeling courses, cheers.